# Notify ListView on layout dynamic change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a ListView:

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        getApplicationContext(), forecastList,
                        R.layout.weather_list_row, new String[] { "forecast",
                                "precipitation", "temperature" }, new int[] {
                                R.id.forecast, R.id.precipitation,
                                R.id.temperature });
                lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and I have a "**R.layout.weather_list_row**" as:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingTop="4dip" android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/forecast" android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000" />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="50dip">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/precipitation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="#00357A"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/weather_status1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="50dip">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/temperature" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#00357A" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/weather_status2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the **R.layout.weather_list_row** I am dynamically changing the **src=** of the **ImageView**.

- **Question:**  How can I notify the ListView, when I change the
  values in the R.layout.weather_list_row?

Comment: Ok, from which event you dynamically get updated for new Images, on That method just call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: I update images in the handler

Comment: update image in the your adapter's getView() and when you have any new update or data then just call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: made a separate class for the adapter, changed the images src in the constructor and then notified data set in the main class, but still nothing..

Comment: ok. this works if i change the image sources in the getView method, but not in constructor

Comment: made a separate class for the adapter. changed the images src in adapter's getView() and call notifyDataSetChanged from any method or any button click event.

Comment: ya. always because every time onNotifyDataSetChanged() will called your adapter's getView() will be called and images are changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: i tried this one, but no result. isn't notifydatasetchanged is for the content, but not for the layout?

Comment: Sorry, that was right, i just had too little knowledge about adapters